# Received on vs Received at

Tags: prepositions

Which is the correct form of the sentence below?

```
The message was received on 10pm, 3rd March 2017.
```

Or

```
The message was received at 10pm, 3rd March 2017.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preposition ***on*** is used with dates and the preposition ***at*** is used when talking about times of day:

> The message was received **on** March 3rd, 2017 **at** 10 PM.