# Which preposition should I use, "on" 1st January or "in" 1st January?

Tags: prepositions, dates

Which preposition should I use, *"on"* 1st January or *"in"* 1st January?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147526/received-on-vs-received-at/147528#147528

Answer (score 2):

You use the preposition on, not in, with dates. So you say:

On the 1st January or on 1st January.